# Prolog undefined procedure error?

Tags: prolog

just recently started learning Prolog, and I have NO idea why I'm getting this error.

This is the 'code' in the .pl file:

```
bigger(elephant, horse).
bigger(horse, donkey).
bigger(donkey, dog).
bigger(donkey, monkey).

isbigger(X, Y) :- bigger(X, Y).
isbigger(X, Y) :- bigger(X, Z),print(Z),print(’ ’) ,isbigger(Z, Y).
```

Whenever I attempt to check which animal is bigger I get this error:

```
  1 ?- bigger(donkey, monkey).
  ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: bigger/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

Any help please?

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure there is no other code in the file. It seems isbigger/2 does not appear anywhere in your code, so this error is not relevant to what you posted here

Comment: Nope, there is no other code! I don't think isbigger/2 matters because I still get an error with bigger/2

Comment: @Eggy: you have to consult your file. Execute `[filename].` at your prolog prompt where _filename_ is the name of your .pl file.

Comment: @gusbro - thanks, it worked. For some reason I was entering it like this ['filename'] (which is obviously wrong).

Comment: @Eggy: It should be ok also to put quotes. You either forgot the dot after or you mispelled the filename.

Answer (score 1):

You need an assert I think:

```
assert(bigger(donkey, monkey)).
```

Just started today myself and this one took me a while to figure out.

Good luck!